# Intellij IDEA тормозит после аварийного завершения бесконечного цикла

Tags: java, intellij-idea

В Intellij IDEA, когда я случайно(по тупости) создаю и запускаю программу с бесконечным циклом,ПК по ясным причинам начинает сильно тужиться. Но когда я вручную останавливаю программу,процессор все равно продолжает выполнять какие-то операции(загруженность 100%) и конечно,все и вся ужасно виснет. 
Почему так происходит и можно ли это как-то исправить?

Код примера:

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
int x = 14;
for (int i = 0; 0 < 10; i++) {
System.out.println(x++);
}}}
```

В конечном итоге запуск(Run) такого кода будет увеличивать значение x бесконечно и после остановки(Stop), начинаются все тормоза.

Comment: опишите подробнее где и как создается цикл, как останавливаете "вручную" программу, какую именно программу?

Comment: внес подробности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В окне вывода появляется слишком много информации и именно из-за этого IntelliJ начинает тормозить. Если записывать данные отдельный в файл, этот эффект должен пропасть.